# Error importing script in vue file in Vue 3

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-mix

I'm using `laravel-mix` with Vue 3 and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/App.vue 2:0-54
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App.js/?vue&type=script&lang=js' in './resources/js/components'
```

components/App.vue

```html
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script src="./App.js/"></script>
```

components/App.js

```js
export default {
    name: "App",
};
```

In my previous projects with Vue 2 and Laravel 7 I didn't get these errors. Now I'm using Vue 3  and Laravel 8, but don't know how to fix it. I have installed `vue-loader` and `vue-template-compiler` so I guess it should work.

Does Vue 3 allow importing a script from a separated js file? In Vue 2 that was possible (I like to separate the HTML from the JS because of some issues with my editor and also for better organization.)

Comment: Should that extra forward slash at the end of App.js be there? Looks suspect `<script src="./App.js/"></script>`

Comment: @steve16351 you are right! Thanks for pointing that out; I hadn't figured out that by myself. If you post it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not related to Vue3, just you added slash after file so it's understanding as a dir.

```
<script src="./App.js/"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="./App.js"></script>
```